# how to remove following generic

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

```
@Autowired
SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public SPLoginUser loginUser(final LoginBean loginBean) {
    final Map<String, Object> inParamMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    inParamMap.put(DAOConstants.EMAIL, loginBean.getEmail());
    inParamMap.put(DAOConstants.PASSWORD, loginBean.getPassword());
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    final List<SPLoginUser> list = sessionFactory
            .getCurrentSession()
            .getNamedQuery(
                    DAOConstants.SQL_FUNCTIONS.NAMED_NATIVE_QUERY.LOGIN_USER)
            .setProperties(inParamMap).list();

    if (list != null && list.size() == 1) {
        if (list.get(0).getErrorCode() == 200) {
            return list.get(0);
        } else {
            throw new UserNotFoundException(list.get(0).getErrorMessage());
        }
    } else {
        throw new UserNotFoundException();
    }
}
```

in the above mentioned code of my spring controller i want to remove:

```
    if (list != null && list.size() == 1) {
        if (list.get(0).getErrorCode() == 200) {
            return list.get(0);
        } else {
            throw new UserNotFoundException(list.get(0).getErrorMessage());
        }
    } else {
        throw new UserNotFoundException();
    }
enter code here
```

and wants this to be generic and in 1 or 2 lines.

please help me out. this is throughout my spring mvc 4 application.

Comment: Have you tried extracting a method?

Comment: Yes I have created a generic method, but i thought it will be great if there is some kind of annotation which can do such checks rather then calling method.

Comment: Is it an application you are building from scratch? I'm asking because there might be an elegant solution in conjunction with Spring Data for you.

Comment: Yes thats correct. I am making this appliction from scratch.
all the database transctions happen in stored procedures and I call stored procedure using hibernate.